# Find the coordinates of the closest point between two lines in 3d space.

Tags: matrices, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have not worked with 3d coordinate systems for a while and this is giving me a bit of a struggle. I have the coordinates of four points in XYZ. Two points I use to generate the line AB and the other two I use to generate line CD. I would like to find the closest XYZ coordinate on AB to line CD and the closest XYZ coordinate on CD to line AB. My idea was to find the equation for the perpendicular line between AB and CD and then find the intersection of this new line with AB and CD. However, I do not really know where to begin. If anyone could help that would be very much appreciated

Comment: Who is the person who asks to close a question which displays evidently some research ?

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1993953)

Comment: @Jean Marie: I suscribe completely your very pertinent question about that "person".

Comment: First thing that you need to clarify is whether you are looking for the points on line segments $AB$ and $CD$ that are closest to each other or anywhere on lines through $AB$ and $CD$. As you mention _line_, I assume it is the latter. If so, the link shared by Jean Marie already has a solution.

Comment: I avise you to have a look at this [reference](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/dorrie/69.pdf). It is a chapter of a very good old book by Dörrie, re-written in a modern way.